# Python 3.5 error with curses module (not supported)

Tags: python-3.x, ide, python-curses

I've been trying to start using curses and I saw this code:

```
import curses

stdscr = curses.initscr()
```

but whenever I run it, it displays the following message:

> Redirection is not supported.
>   Aborted (disconnected)

I already have the curses module, and I'm using Python 3.5. I'm also using the Wing IDE, so is there anything else I need to install to make the IDE support curses?

Comment: Works on my Mac console with Python 3.5.1 but not Wing IDE.  Wing IDE Support says you need to use the console with curses: http://wingide.992054.n4.nabble.com/Wing-not-starting-td992703.html